# Как отфильтровать массив по условию?

Tags: javascript, массивы, filter

Нужно отфильтровать массив `arr1`:

```js
const arr1 = [
{name: 'Вася', surname: 'Пупкин', age: 22},
{name: 'Петя', surname: 'Залупкин', age: 23},
{name: 'Ваня', surname: 'Быков', age: 22},
{name: 'Володя', surname: 'Пупкин', age: 21},
]

const obj = {name: 'Петя', surname: 'Пупкин', age: 21}

const arr2 = arr1.filter(item => {
                 //Здесь код
} 

console.log(arr2)
```

Чтобы результат был таков:

```js
arr2 = [
{name: 'Вася', surname: 'Пупкин', age: 22},
{name: 'Петя', surname: 'Залупкин', age: 23},
{name: 'Володя', surname: 'Пупкин', age: 21}
]
```

На словах: у первого элемента совпадает фамилия - оставляем, у второго совпадает имя - оставляем, у третьего ничего не совпадает - убираем, у четвертого совпадает возраст - оставляем.

Comment: Нужно два прогона - первый сбор инфы, второй фильтрация на основе этой инфы

Answer (score 3):

```js
const arr1 = [
  { name: 'Вася', surname: 'Пупкин', age: 22 },
  { name: 'Петя', surname: 'Залупкин', age: 23 },
  { name: 'Ваня', surname: 'Быков', age: 22 },
  { name: 'Володя', surname: 'Пупкин', age: 21 },
];
const obj = { name: 'Петя', surname: 'Пупкин', age: 21 };
const ent = Object.entries(obj);

console.log(arr1.filter(item => ent.some(e => e[1] === item[e[0]])));
```

Comment: Лучше const `entries = Object.entries(obj);` и далее `arr1.filter(item => entries.some(([key, val]) => item[key] === val))`: плюс читаемость, минус создание двумерного массива на каждой итерации.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr1 = [
  { name: 'Вася',     surname: 'Пупкин',     age: 22 },
  { name: 'Петя',     surname: 'Залупкин',   age: 23 },
  { name: 'Ваня',     surname: 'Быков',      age: 22 },
  { name: 'Володя',   surname: 'Пупкин',     age: 21 },
]

const obj = {name: 'Петя', surname: 'Пупкин', age: 21}
const keys = Object.keys(obj)

const arr2 = arr1.filter(x => keys.some(k => x[k] === obj[k]))

console.log(arr2)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```